# Is IDA pulling my leg - or can REX.W sometimes not be determined in static analysis?

Tags: ida, x86-64, assembly

NB: I normally dabble with disassembly (i.e. mnemonics) and only ever look at the raw opcodes when I can't avoid it.

I have the following line of disassembly of a Windows x64 kernel mode driver, created by IDA Pro 7.1.180227:

```
xor     edx, edx
```

Now I *know* for a fact that this is in preparation of passing the second parameter to a function via `rdx`. I also know that the intention of that code is to set said pointer argument to `NULL`.

The opcode is `33 D2`. And cross-referencing that with [the reference](http://ref.x86asm.net/coder64.html#x33) or looking at it [in ODA](https://onlinedisassembler.com/odaweb/4CcSHhBe/0) yields the same as with IDA: `xor edx, edx`.

Now what itches me wrong with this disassembly is that `rdx`, as a superset of `edx`, is used elsewhere on that exact code path to store other pointers. So in theory the upper double-word of `rdx` could be "dirty".

And going by the fact that this is x64 code, I'd expect this to read `xor rdx, rdx`. Why is that not how it's presented in the disassembly?

---

Now I understand that, as per section 3.6.1 (Table 3-4) of the [Intel SDM](https://software.intel.com/en-us/articles/intel-sdm) (05/2018) the REX.W Prefix of the opcode can affect the operand size.

For this opcode neither the operand-size (66h) nor the address-size (67h) prefix are present.

So going by the Intel SDM (section "XOR—Logical Exclusive OR") I should indeed be dealing with opcode `33 /r` or instruction `XOR r32, r/m32`, confirming IDAs translation of the opcode. Referring to section 2.1.5 ("Addressing-Mode Encoding of ModR/M and SIB Bytes") of the Intel SDM gives us a clue as to how the operand (`D2`) is encoded and so gives us, from Table 2-2 ("32-Bit Addressing Forms with the ModR/M Byte"): `EDX/DX/DL/MM2/XMM2` as operand.

Figures.

However, that would mean that the "dirty" upper double-word in `rdx` would not be zeroed out and thus a garbled/truncated pointer would end up being passed. Given this is kernel mode code, the consequences should be clear.

I just can't believe that the compiler would make such mistake. So what *am I* missing?

Comment: Could you include some related code? say, code using E/RDX, additional code manipulating it prior to XOR instruction, etc. I've recently encountered a similar issue where after some more thorough investigation the upper half of RDX was indeed always zero, making this an unexploitable bug by the developer.

Comment: duplicate of stackoverflow [Why do x86-64 instructions on 32-bit registers zero the upper part of the full 64-bit register?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11177137), and see also [What is the best way to set a register to zero in x86 assembly: xor, mov or and?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33666617) which explains that 32-bit operand-size is always best (e.g. `xor r10d, r10d` is not shorter than `xor r10,r10`, but Silvermont only recognizes 32-bit operand size as a zeroing idiom!)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

In x86-64, any operation that affects only the lower 32 bits of a register automatically zeros out the upper 32 bits.

The relevant part in the Intel Architecture manual is in Volume 1, 3.4.1.1, which states:

> When in 64-bit mode, operand size determines the number of valid bits
>   in the destination general-purpose register:
>
> - 64-bit operands generate a 64-bit result in the destination general-purpose register.
> - **32-bit operands generate a 32-bit result, zero-extended to a 64-bit
>     result in the destination general-purpose register.**
> - 8-bit and 16-bit operands generate an 8-bit or 16-bit result. The upper 56 bits or 48 bits (respectively) of the destination general-purpose register are
>     not modified by the operation. If the result of an 8-bit or 16-bit
>     operation is intended for 64-bit address calculation, explicitly
>     sign-extend the register to the full 64-bits.

Thus both forms give the same result, and `xor edx, edx` is one byte shorter than `xor rdx, rdx`, so the compiler prefers it.

Comment: By the way, this also gives other intricacies. For example the NOP instruction is normally 0x90, which is actually `xchg eax, eax`. But in 64-bit mode this is not a NOP, because it zeros the upper 32 bits. So `xchg eax, eax` has different encodings in 64-bit and 32-bit mode.

Comment: I read about that somewhere, but I did not make the connection.

Comment: @jakobbotsch I believe opcode 0x90 is always handled as `nop` in all modes. It does not clear top part of `rax`.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky Yes, that's what I meant. They had to find a new encoding for `xchg eax, eax` since that wouldn't be a NOP on x64.

Comment: @jakobbotsch: Where's the issue? xchg eax, eax already had two encodings.

Comment: @Joshua: Right, I think what Jakob meant to say is that *assemblers* can't use the `0x90` short form for `xchg eax,eax` in the asm source, and have to use the `xchg r, r/m32` form with a ModRM byte (http://felixcloutier.com/x86/XCHG.html).  But fun fact, 16 and 64-bit operand sizes can still use `0x90` with a 66 or REX.W prefix.  NASM does assemble `xchg ax,ax` to `66 90` in 64-bit mode.

Comment: @PeterCordes Exactly. I phrased that badly, but we got there in the end!